# How fix problem "column reference "id" is ambiguous" in PostgreSQL function?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In **PostgreSQL** database I have 2 table: `services` and `services_organizations_relationship`. Each organization has a specific list of services.

My next function need to create new records in `services` table, then create relationship between services and organizations and finally return list of all new created services.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test (
    SERVICE_NAME_ARRAY VARCHAR[],
    ACTIVE_ARRAY BOOLEAN[],
    DESCRIPTION_ARRAY TEXT[],
    ORGANIZATION_ID_ARRAY INT[]
) RETURNS TABLE (
    ID UUID,
    NAME VARCHAR,
    ACTIVE BOOLEAN,
    DESCRIPTION TEXT
) AS $$
    BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY
        WITH RESULTS AS (
            INSERT INTO SERVICES (NAME, ACTIVE, DESCRIPTION) 
            SELECT 
                UNNEST(ARRAY[SERVICE_NAME_ARRAY]) AS NAME,
                UNNEST(ARRAY[ACTIVE_ARRAY]) AS ACTICE,
                UNNEST(ARRAY[DESCRIPTION_ARRAY]) AS DESCRIPTION
            RETURNING ID, NAME, ACTIVE, DESCRIPTION
        ),
        GENERATE_SERVICES_ORGANIZATIONS_RELATIONSHIP AS 
        (
            INSERT INTO SERVICES_ORGANIZATIONS_RELATIONSHIP (SERVICE_ID, ORGANIZATION_ID)
            SELECT
                UNNEST(ARRAY_AGG(ID)) AS SERVICE_ID,
                UNNEST(ARRAY[ORGANIZATION_ID_ARRAY]) AS ORGANIZATION_ID
            FROM RESULTS
            ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT SERVICES_ORGANIZATIONS_RELATIONSHIP_UNIQUE_KEY DO NOTHING
        )
        SELECT ID, NAME, ACTIVE, DESCRIPTION FROM RESULTS;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I call this function:

```
SELECT * FROM test(ARRAY['SLOT', 'JTC'], ARRAY[TRUE, FALSE], ARRAY['SLOT', 'JTC'], ARRAY[30572, 30573]);
```

I see such error:

```
SQL Error [42702]: ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous
Details: It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
Where: PL/pgSQL function test(character varying[],boolean[],text[],integer[]) line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final line of the query should be

```
SELECT result.id, result.name,... FROM result
```

To avoid such collisions, you can use different names for the columns in the `RETURNS TABLE` clause (which are variables) and the columns in the queries (e.g. by using aliases).

Comment: Well, in my case the only working solution was the changing of column names in `RETURNS TABLE` clause as you recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
GENERATE_SERVICES_ORGANIZATIONS_RELATIONSHIP AS 
        (
            INSERT INTO SERVICES_ORGANIZATIONS_RELATIONSHIP (SERVICE_ID, ORGANIZATION_ID)
            SELECT
                UNNEST(ARRAY_AGG(t1.ID)) AS SERVICE_ID,
                UNNEST(ARRAY[ORGANIZATION_ID_ARRAY]) AS ORGANIZATION_ID
            FROM RESULTS t1
            ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT SERVICES_ORGANIZATIONS_RELATIONSHIP_UNIQUE_KEY DO NOTHING
        )
```